# What does this component on a +12V wire do?

Tags: components

I have a 12V LED lamp in a caravan that does not work. On the +12V wire I found the following component which seems to be the problem, as bypassing it makes the lamp work again.

My question is: What is this component and what is it supposed to do? Protecting against reversing the polarity or something else?

[image: component on +12V wire]

Comment: Looks like a surface mount fuse.

Comment: Very bad workmanship for a part used in a caravan. Soldering a stranded wire to a PCB this way is not vibration proof in an automotive environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a [surface mount fuse.](https://docs.rs-online.com/aae3/0900766b80785544.pdf)  From the code marked on it ("P"), it would be rated for 3 amperes.

Replace the surface mount fuse with a 3 ampere fuse or replace the board with a fuse holder and a standard 3 ampere fuse.

Answer (score 2):

It is a surface mount fuse, mounted on a small PCB for connecting it to wires.